# Yup validation - check if value doesn't match other field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, yup

Hi I am trying to find a way to compare 2 fields and validate only if they are not equal.

This is the only idea I was able to come up with but it doesn't work:

```
yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .notOneOf(
      [FormField.houseHoldMembers as any],
      'error message',
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the two values and validate only if they are not equal like this:

```
const mySchema = yup.object({
  text1: yup.number().required(),
  text2: yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .when(["text1"], (text1, schema) => {
      console.log(schema);
      return schema.notOneOf([text1], "the two values should not be equal");
    })
});
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-compare-esfs1i?file=/src/App.js) for a live working example of this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Shorted:

```
const schema = yup.object({
   field1: yup.number().required(),
   field2: yup
     .number()
     .required()
     .notOneOf([yup.ref('field1'), null], 'The two values should not be equal'),
});
```